# Writing with one button

Tags: java, javafx

I am currently in school were we got tasked to invent a solution for writing with only one button on the keyboard. The main task is writing a report about it, but it also requires to make a prototype. That's where I am stuck. 
I have made a JavaFX with all the buttons from a-å(Norwegian letters), and the plan is to pick a random button (say the g-key on the keyboard) and for each push it will move to the next letter. On a double click on the button it should print out the letter to a text box, and the next click move on to the next letter in line. That way you should be able to write simple text messages.

I am really stuck right now on how to make the "G-key" switch from the different buttons, and how to make it print out to the text field.  Also I am fairly new to programming and JavaFX, and apologizes for any stupid question. Also not sure if JavaFX is the simplest way to do this, but choose it because I am most familiar with it.

My code so far: 
sample.fxml:

```
    <GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
            <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
    <HBox spacing="10" alignment="bottom_right"
          GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
        <Button text="A" fx:id="pushed" onAction="#write"/>
        <Button text="B" />
        <Button text="C"/>
        <Button text="D"/>
        <Button text="E"/>
    </HBox>
    <HBox spacing="10" alignment="bottom_right"
          GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
        <Button text="F"/>
        <Button text="G"/>
        <Button text="H"/>
        <Button text="I"/>
        <Button text="J"/>
        <Button text="K"/>
    </HBox>
    <HBox spacing="10" alignment="bottom_right"
          GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4"></HBox>
    <HBox spacing="10" alignment="bottom_right"
          GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5">
        <Button text="R"/>
        <Button text="S"/>
        <Button text="T"/>
        <Button text="U"/>
        <Button text="V"/>
        <Button text="X"/>
    </HBox>
    <HBox spacing="10" alignment="bottom_right"
          GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="6">
        <Button text="Y"/>
        <Button text="Z"/>
        <Button text="Æ"/>
        <Button text="Ø"/>
        <Button text="Å"/>
    </HBox>
    <HBox spacing="10" alignment="bottom_right"
          GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="7">
        <Button text="Space"/>
        <Button text="."/>
    </HBox>
</GridPane>
```

Controller.java:

```
package sample;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;

public class Controller {

    public void write(ActionEvent event){

    }
}
```

Main.java:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can immediately simplify your task by using `ToggleButton`s instead of normal ones.

Comment: As keyboard input make 1 "any key" button, say with id "anykey", with `setOnMouseClicked` you can get the MouseEvent and ist `getClickCount`. Now you can detect double clicks. The buttons could be used as output: which key would be taken when double clicked. Toggle buttons (or even radio buttons) could be used.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample app you can play with. I didn't implement `BACKSPACE`, `TAB`, `ENTER` etc. I also didn't test the app to see if I correctly handled restarting the character cycle after going through all of the characters. This should be a good starting point. In this app, I coded change of character on single click, and append text to `TextField` on double click. How to detect double click came from @JamesD answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231209/javafx-reacting-to-single-double-and-triple-click).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class OneButtonWriter extends Application {

    final static String ALPHABETS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789;~!@#$%^&*()_+~!@#$%^&*()_+[]\\{}|;':\",./<>?";
    final static String[] ACTION_KEYS = {"TAB", "ENTER"};

    List<String> keys = new ArrayList();//Holds each key

    int currentKey = 0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        loadKeys();//Add all keys from ALPHABETS and ACTION_KEYS to keys arralist as individual keys.

        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();

        Button button = new Button();

        //Code from Jame_D answer on double click
        Duration maxTimeBetweenSequentialClicks = Duration.millis(500);

        PauseTransition clickTimer = new PauseTransition(maxTimeBetweenSequentialClicks);
        final IntegerProperty sequentialClickCount = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
        clickTimer.setOnFinished(event -> {
            int count = sequentialClickCount.get();
            if (count == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("Single click");
                textArea.appendText(button.getText());//if single click append text to textarea
            }
            if (count == 2)
            {
                System.out.println("Double click");
                currentKey++;//if double click increment currentKey
                if(currentKey == keys.size())//If currentkey equal the keys size set current key back to A or index zero ***I HAVE NOT TESTED THIS***
                {
                    currentKey = 0;
                }

                button.setText(keys.get(currentKey));
            }
            if (count == 3) System.out.println("Triple click");
            if (count > 3) System.out.println("Multiple click: "+count);
            sequentialClickCount.set(0);
        });


        button.setPrefSize(100, 100);
        button.setText(keys.get(currentKey));
        button.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {            
            sequentialClickCount.set(sequentialClickCount.get()+1);
            clickTimer.playFromStart();

        });

        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.getChildren().add(textArea);
        vbox.getChildren().add(new StackPane(button));

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(vbox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private void loadKeys()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < ALPHABETS.length(); i++)
        {
            keys.add(Character.toString(ALPHABETS.charAt(i)));
        }

        for(String actionKey : ACTION_KEYS)
        {
            keys.add(actionKey);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this will help a lot!